# Dialogflow won't display proper time using @sys.date-time

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm trying to use @sys.date-time to get the current time when I type "Good Morning". Sadly, all it returns is "Good Morning! Right now it is 08:00:00/12:00:00"

How do I do this? Do I need to use a webhook? How do I go about doing that?
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R56Hx.png)

Comment: Can you show your intent? Post a screenshot please.

Comment: Added to original post. I know its very basic stuff in Dialogflow I just am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

Diagloflow understands that `morning` is the period between 08:00-12:00 that's why you're not getting the current time. For that you will need a webhook.

You can read all about webhooks and how to create one in the official [docs](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment)

Comment: I still don't completely understand it

Comment: What do you not understand? Dialogflow treats `morning` as a period of time, since it is a period of time.

Comment: No I mean I don't completely understand webhooks, even from the docs